# How to calculate table height in watch in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, watch

I have a table and I give a ref to it.

```
<table ref="table"></table>
```

I want to calculate the height of this table in watcher:

```
watch: {

   buttonClicked: {
      immediate: true,
      handler() {
        this.$nextTick(() => {
          const tableElement = this.$refs.table.$el;
          const tableOffsetTop = tableElement.getBoundingClientRect().top;
        });
      },
    },
}
```

But I am getting an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$el')

I tried ti fix it with this.$nextTick but this time I cannot calculate it right.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Since you're using an arrow function, `this`is locally scoped, not the global one. Try using a 'classic' function instead - i.e. `this.$nextTick(function() {`

Comment: try this. ` var self=this; this.$nextTick(() => {const tableElement = self.$refs.table.$el;const tableOffsetTop = tableElement.getBoundingClientRect().top;});`